# Autocomplete jQuery with mysql database's data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I created this jquery autocomplete but as a result it returns [].
In the users table there are 2 fields: "ID" (int autoincrement) and "Name (varchar)" and are populated.

auto_complete_jquery.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><!-- Insert your title here --></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
 <script>
$(function() {
$("#tags").autocomplete({source: "name.php", dataType: 'json'});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

connection.php:

```
<?php
    $hostname="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $conn=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
        $dbs = mysql_select_db("jquery_test",$conn);
    if(!$conn)
    {
        echo("Error connection MySQL.");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

name.php:

```
<?php
    $return_arr = array();
    $term = $_GET["term"];
    include "connection.php";
    $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH(Name) AGAINST('".$term."*')") or die (mysql_error());
    ?>
            <?php

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
             {
                $row_array['value'] = $row['tagName'];
                array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
             }

             mysql_close($conn);
             $json=json_encode($return_arr);
             echo $json;
            ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked if the File is Queried by the Browser and has the right contents?

Comment: Firstly, don't use mysql_ methods, they are deprecated, use mysqli instead http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php, secondly why not try using `SELECT * FROM users WHERE `name` LIKE "%?%"`

Comment: Perfect! I used the LIKE operator and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you looking for this,

```
$( "#PopulateData" ).autocomplete({
            minLength:2, 
            delay: 50,  
            selectFirst: true,
            open: function () {
                $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element.width(409);
            },
            source:function(request,response){
             removeConflict.ajax({
                  url: 'remotefile.php?list='+$('#PopulateData').val(),
                  data: request,
                  dataType: null,
                  type: "GET",
                  success: function(data){
                    var listarray= jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    response(
                    $.map(listarray, function(item) {
                        var text = item.jsonpropertyA;
                        var code = item.jsonpropertyb;
                        console.log(text )
                        return {
                            label: code,
                            value: text

                        }
                    })
                   )},
                 error:function(data){
                     console.log(data)
                  }
             });
           },
          select: function( event, ui ) {
            console.log('value:'+ ui.item.value + ',label:'+ui.item.label);
        }
    });
```

json object is returned from the server response, and the label and value is returned to the  autocomplete text box.

Note: you've can do some modification which suites your. :)